Middleman V4 i18n
Can I get Middleman do the following:
Let's say I have a website that only has 1 page. Let's name the page index.html.
Now I want this page to be available in multiple languages.
Can I do something like having one index.html.erb and n language files.
locales/en.yml
locales/de.yml
...

So that I don't need to create
  |   |   +-- index.html.erb
  |   |   +-- index.en.html.erb

when i do
middleman build

it should generate multiple index.html Files (index.html, index_en.html, ...) one for each language.
Is that possible? If yes how? Thanks in advance!
